# Si creas una execute de una vez se cierra despues de la ejecucion? java.sql

Tags: java, mysql

```
DriverManager.getConnection(nameDB,userDB,passDB).createStatement().execute("el sql que queremos ejecutar")
```

Se que es una tonteria, pero después de ejecutar este **execute** ¿se cerraría la conexión directamente o hay que capturarla y cerrarla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que cerrarla. La conexión seguirá abierta si no la cierras y a la larga el contenedor (por ejemplo Tomcat) comenzaría a perder recursos... y podría colapsar.

Eso sí algunos drivers de JDBC tratan de identificar estos casos y silenciosamente hacen el trabajo de cerrar las conexiones cuando detectan que ya no son usadas. No hay que confiar en dicha funcionalidad porque nunca sabes si es lo suficientemente inteligente para darse cuenta.

Habitualmente puedes cerrar la conexión automáticamente usando un `try (<recursos>)`.

Por ejemplo:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(nameDB,userDB,passDB)) {
  conn.createStatement().execute("el sql que queremos ejecutar");
} // Cierra los recursos automáticamente al finalizar el "try".
```